# How to query the xml in SQL XML on a SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, sqlxml

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. There is a table called `Documents` with the following schema:

```
 Id            int     PK      
 DocumentXml   xml
```

The xml documents all look something like:

```
<docroot>
    <name>Some Name</name>
</docroot>
```

I want to select all the records where the text value of `/docroot/name` begins with an "S" (case-insenstive).

How do I execute this query with the best performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the performance - but you can do something like this:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Documents
WHERE DocumentXml.value('(/docroot/name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') LIKE 'S%'
```

If your database collation is case-insensitive, this `LIKE` operation will be case-insensitive, too.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all the records where
>   the text value of `/docroot/name` begins
>   with an "S" (case-insenstive).

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
/*/name[starts-with(translate(.,'S','s'), 's')]
```

Comment: The XPath is good, but the part I was having trouble with was combining the XPath and the SQL

Comment: @smartcaveman: Sorry, I can't help you there, but I'll ask some knowledgable people.