# Parse XML & Inner XML in SQL Server in same query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to Parse XML & Inner XML in SQL Server 2008 in same query.
Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further, what is the xml and how you want to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a bit ambiguous, but I asked a question that sounds similar.  See if some of the answers help you: [How to query the xml in SQL XML on a SQL Server 2008 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086619/how-to-query-the-xml-in-sql-xml-on-a-sql-server-2008-database)